# How to parse the Json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Json array as below

```
 {
 "Level":{
      "@attributes":
        {
                "value":"","type":"RelyingParty","others":"false","id":"1"
        }
     },
   "Role":{
     "@attributes":
              {
             "uuid":"838f7ee2-f11c-48f9-887f-8e485b74169b","type":"ADMIN"
              }
     },
   "Timeline":"2012",
   "Timezone":"GMT+330"
  }
```

How can i parse the above json data using jquery and store it in a javascript array. Because i am new to json any help on this will be very useful for me.

Comment: Second result on Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+json

Comment: That's a JSON object, actually an object fragment. Google JSON.parse() - that's all you need.

Comment: how about doing some research first...

Comment: Did you try `jQuery.parseJSON( data )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've quoted is not valid JSON, and even with a minimal modification, it wouldn't be an *array*. I suspect you just mean "object" (e.g., what PHP calls an associative array; really it's a map). What you've quoted looks like *part* of a JSON object definition, but it's missing the initial `{`.

jQuery offers [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for this very purpose:

```
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(strContainingJSON);
```

So adding the leading `{`, here it is:

```
str = '{' +
      '    "Level": {' +
      '        "@attributes": {' +
      '            "value": "",' +
      '            "type": "RelyingParty",' +
      '            "others": "false",' +
      '            "id": "1"' +
      '        }' +
      '    },' +
      '    "Role": {' +
      '        "@attributes": {' +
      '            "uuid": "838f7ee2-f11c-48f9-887f-8e485b74169b",' +
      '            "type": "ADMIN"' +
      '        }' +
      '    },' +
      '    "Timeline": "2012",' +
      '    "Timezone": "GMT+330"' +
      '}';
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
console.log(x.Timeline); // "2012"
```

Of course, you probably get `str` from somewhere else (loading it from ajax or something), rather than directly in a string as in the above, but the end result is the same. Also note that if you *are* using ajax to load the JSON, if it's served with the correct MIME type, [jQuery will parse it automatically](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), and then hand your ajax `success` function the resulting object.

If you really want an *array* (an ordered list), put `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end, creating a one-entry array containing the object:

```
str = '[' +
      '    {' +
      '        "Level": {' +
      '            "@attributes": {' +
      '                "value": "",' +
      '                "type": "RelyingParty",' +
      '                "others": "false",' +
      '                "id": "1"' +
      '            }' +
      '        },' +
      '        "Role": {' +
      '            "@attributes": {' +
      '                "uuid": "838f7ee2-f11c-48f9-887f-8e485b74169b",' +
      '                "type": "ADMIN"' +
      '            }' +
      '        },' +
      '        "Timeline": "2012",' +
      '        "Timezone": "GMT+330"' +
      '    }' +
      ']';
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
console.log(x[0].Timeline); // "2012"
```

Comment: JSON starts and ends with `{` `}` as it's an object literal. `[` `]` are for arrays inside a JSON object.

Comment: I have formed the above json data using json_encode function php. it outputs only the above json data,

Comment: @Interrobang: No, see http://json.org. `[1, 2, 3]` is [valid JSON](jsonlint.com). The outermost structure can be an object *or* an array.

Comment: @gowthamkumar: You've left off the leading `{` at the least.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Sorry i missed leading { .

Comment: @gowthamkumar: No worries. Your question is answered now, right?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Still i have some confusion in assigning the parsed data into an javascript array using jquery each function. can u please help me on it.

Comment: @gowthamkumar: You never said anything about `each` in your question. But basically, just use it. Once you've done the `var x = jQuery.parseJSON(str);`, you can loop through the properties of the object via `jQuery.each(x, function(propName, propValue) { ... });`